# How to put the menu over the content?

Tags: php, jquery, css, drupal-7, zen

I'm developing a website with drupal 7. I use zen theme 7.x/5.x. I want to put the menu over the content. The content it's a slideshow in the front page. I try to put the two menus in the content region, above the main content. But it doesn't work. The css code it's:

```
#block-system-main-menu{
position:absolute;
left:7px;
top:162px;
}
#block-menu-menu-menu-socialmedia{
position:absolute;
left:7px;
top:436px;
}
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_slideshow-page{
position:absolute;
left:165px; 
top:68px;
}
```

How I does it? I've to modify the page--front.tpl.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you want your menu to overlap your content?
Try and use `z-index`.
Like so:

```
#block-system-main-menu{
position:absolute;
left:7px;
top:162px;
z-index:2;
}
#block-menu-menu-menu-socialmedia{
position:absolute;
left:7px;
top:436px;
z-index:2;
}
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_slideshow-page{
position:absolute;
left:165px; 
top:68px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Higher the `z-index` the higher the ordering on the page.